# How to turnoff capturing sound from expo-camera when taking pictures

Tags: react-native, expo, camera, face-detection, expo-camera

<Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={Camera.Constants.Type.front} ref={ref} faceDetectorSettings={{ mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.accurate, detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.none, runClassifications: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.none, }} onFacesDetected={({ faces }) => { if (faces.length > 0 && !isFunctionExecuted) { takepic(); console.debug("face detection completed"); setFunctionExecuted(true); sendtoapi() } }}/>